# How does a "permanent" magnet with switch work?

Tags: electromagnetism

We have several magnetic stands on my university, see [here](http://www.spearandjackson.com.au/products/EC-E901). This stand has a button which makes you able to turn the magnet off and on. It is quite hard to press the button, it seems like something mechanical. But it must be a permanent magnet since it doesn't run on electricity, so I wondered, how is it possible to "turn off" a permanent magnet? Or am I missing something?

EDIT

In reaction to CuriousOne:

If the button causes the magnet inside to move, than how does this work since the button seems to be one solid pin inside the stand, see the two images.

[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mechanical button lowers or raises the magnet, which changes the effective force between it and the steel plate that the base attaches to. You are correct, one can not turn a permanent magnet off this way, but one can greatly change the force between it and a magnetic material by changing the distance.

After looking it up I have to correct myself. One particular design doesn't actually lower or raise the magnet but it turns a cylindrical magnet in an assembly between two magnetic jokes. This is a very important difference to my original suggestion, which would never completely eliminate the force between the magnet and the base plate. In the design shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_base it's the change in symmetry that can essentially completely cancel the field. It's quite ingenious, really.

Comment: That does make sense. But how does this button do this, since it seems to be one solid pin. Ive edited the question with some added images. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I can't tell you the detailed construction that's inside the black box. Mr. Screwdriver can, but he should only be used on property that belongs to you. Maybe you can get permission from the lab manager to open one of these things (there might be a broken one around)? It's worth a try and in a school setting curiosity is never embarrassing.

Comment: Oh wow, so what it basically does is increasing the range by using iron blocks when it is on and decrease the range by using material which isn't ferric? That is pretty cool.

Comment: The rotation changes the symmetry of the magnetic field. In the off position the North and South poles of the cylindrical magnet are being "shorted" magnetically by the jokes and very little of the field extends to the base plate. In the on position one joke is magnetized by the North and one by the South pole of the rotated magnet, and the entire magnetic circuit is closed by the base plate.

Comment: What are "jokes" in this context?

Comment: @ThePhoton: Hehehe... they are the outcrops of a non-native speaker who keeps stumbling over the same trivial mistakes in English over and over, again. Take that with an egg yolk or a magnetic yoke, whichever is funnier in this context. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The push-pull part is a cylindrical permanent magnet.
The main body is divided into two unequal parts by a non-magnetic section.
In the non-magnetic state the inner magnet is 'shorted' in the larger section.
In the magnetic state one end of the inner magnet is pushed beyond the non-magnetic section to create an external pole.

Answer (score 0):

There is another explanation for this and a different design that could be used for something like this. There is a good explanation for this alternate design at this link (https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magswitch).

Answer (score -2):

With the push button mag stand  the inner magnet does not rotate. It moves in a axial direction. Changing the magnetic flux path.

Comment: Could you please add more information into your answer? It seems more like a comment rather than an answer. You can comment on other people's questions and answers once you've got enough reputation. Until then please make sure that your answer contains enough information.